# Can I re-enter the UAE with a passport that expires in less than 6 months?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, uae

I went home on vacation to India from the UAE. I will return on 17 February. However, my passport will expire on 14 May. Will I be allowed to enter UAE on my return trip? Is there any problem I will face because my passport will not be valid for 6 months beyond my re-entry date into the UAE?

Comment: As a start, what is your nationality?

Comment: @DavidRicherby OP didn't, the editor did that. I'll roll it back to the original (from memory when it was in the review queue). Why don't you now make your comment an answer. I suspect the 'edit' confused the poster.

Comment: @ David Richerby I believe the question is still valid because sometimes a legal resident is exempt from the requirement. For example USA Permanent Resident returning to the USA can enter the USA with only their Permanent Resident Card.

Comment: It only needs to be valid on the day you re-enter - see my answer

Comment: @SheikPaul Your edit to the question caused a huge amount of confusion. As a user with 2000+ reputation, you are trusted to edit posts without those edits being reviewed by others. That means you must be careful, and you're trusted to know what you're doing. One thing that you should know by now is that answers go in the answer box and you must _never_ edit a question to put the answer inside the question. That holds even more so when the answer that you edited in appears to have been completely wrong; it was also unsourced.

Comment: @David https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/united-arab-emirates/entry-requirements Are you suggesting a government like uk.gov website is unreliable? What I added was not an answer because it was implicit the OP is a UAE resident and hence the standard blurb about passport validity might not apply, hence not an answer. Your other suggestions are well noted.

Comment: @SheikPaul Perhaps, if you'd sourced the quote, it would have been possible to evaluate its accuracy...

Comment: @pnuts I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: @pnuts Kindly delete it. I didn't create it. I believe someone edited the question, I reviewed it and approved. Didn't notice the new tag created. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was prohibited from traveling for having my visa expiring within 14 days (the officer's specification) upon arrival from a jaunt to Istanbul.  Here are my details, which might not the same as your situation.

- American with work visa to work in UAE for a government agency.
- Work visa was going to expire in 14 days, my trip was for 10 days.  My employer had not started the procedure to renew it for another three years.
- This was in 2012 in Abu Dhabi

My guess is that you should be fine, but from years of experience, my advice is to not mess around with the bureaucracy.  Get something - anything - from your employment showing proof of employment to accompany you, and, if possible, renew your three year visa early before leaving.

Comment: Well, under the current rules, OP is 100% fine

Comment: @Crazydre - I agree; it's just always good to get as much documentation and confirmation, in my experience. Rules change there, depending on the person you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=ae&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=ae&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     residents of the United Arab Emirates must be valid **on
>     arrival**.

So, because you have a UAE residence permit, it's enough if your pasport is valid on the day you re-enter UAE.

Make sure to show your residence permit as well as your passport at check-in. If they try to deny you boarding, ask them to check Timatic, putting the UAE in "alien residency"

Comment: @pnuts OP went on vacation to their home country, India, strongly implying they live in the UAE. And I don't assume them to be in the UAE illegally.

Comment: @pnuts OP applied the indian-citizens tag, and said they'll "return" to the UAE